# How to best improve a Drow Warlock to act as a Blaster

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, warlock, ranged-attack, striker

I have a first draft of a Drow Warlock blaster here:  http://db.tt/9ANVnzA8 (PDF)

I like the Drow and the Warlock pieces, but am open to suggestions on other ways to improve the character.  Is Sorcerer-King the best pact?  Are the encounter and daily powers I chose good options, or are there likely better options?  Does the crossbow/rod mix make sense as equipped?

I appreciate any feedback, both on the character and how better to phrase this question for this forum.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any narrative requirements? Any DPS requirements?

Comment: No, but as much DPS as possible would be nice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that we are optimizing maximal DPR:

Stats, pre-racial:

```
STR 10
CON 10
DEX 11
INT 14
WIS 8
CHA 18
```

A 20 charisma is necessary for a maximum DPR for +1 to accuracy and damage. 13 dex, not 15, cause we're using it to qualify for feats. Int is nice, but secondary and doesn't govern damage.

Ignore the hand crossbow. Completely. Grab yourself a dagger if you really must.

Beyond that, looks solid.

Your at-will DPR with a 20 charisma against a level 1 block of tofu:

Eldritch Blast:

$$
\left(1-\frac{12+1-5-1}{20}-.05\right)\times(5.5+2\times3.5+5)+.05\times(10+2\times6+5)=11.85
$$

Hand of Blight:

$$\left(1-\frac{12+1-5-1+.65\times2}{20}-.05\right)\times(4.5+2\times3.5+5)+.05\times(8+2\times6+5)=10.07$$
 If it's just you, the CA isn't worth it, though this is a "high accuracy" attack as described by our prior question. Nominally, you should also factor in the 65% of combat advantage with the rest of your party's DPR, which isn't huge, but may or may not be worth 1.5 DPR. Interesting situational call, especially since it's fort based.

Typical monster HP at level 1 is 32. Therefore you'll take roughly 32/11.85=2.7 rounds to kill a mob.  Or... pretty poor. Inverting this according to [DPR King 2.0](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22105109/DPR_King_Candidates_2.0) gets you .37. As 4.0 is the threshold for a "pretty fair striker" On the other hand, there's not a whole lot you can do before magic items and suchlike.

To improve DPR past here we have to make pretty substantial changes to class and or race.

Edit:

In response to: "I'm evaluating changing my daily and going CON-based. What races would you suggest that might augment that well? I like the pretentious characteristics of Elven types, but am not necessarily a huge fan of commoners despising me due to my race."

There is the option of commoner reeducation via pain, fire, and suffering :) But for a conlock... warforged can be fun... Eladrin works for chalock... For optimal conlock, I'd say revenant (since it means you don't change anything) and can cherrypick your past race for RP or feat cherrypicking purposes. For a vestiglock... I'd normally recommend helf, but since you're not going into paragon... eeh. Mind you, you will be an undead walking around... so... this may not be the bestest choice ever.

In conclusion be tiefling or tiefling revenant. Tieflings have some fantastic feats to cherrypick from, revenant has a better stat lineup and survivability. Grab *Blood Pact of Cania* for: " A scaling untyped damage bonus to all CON'LOCK powers really helps out Tiefling Con'locks be more optimal, but for REVENANT TIEFLINGS it is a dream come true!"

Of course, you will be an undead with ancient demon blood in your veins having sold your soul to a sorocerer-king somewhere in your world... but you won't be a drow :).

I recommend disguising your smell with an "alcohol" addiction (much better to stink of booze) and investing in some "genuine flesh-tone" makeup.

Comment: What I'm gathering from this is no matter what I do, as a warlock blaster, I'm probably going to be ostracized by commoners on RP situations.  Warforged looks nice with its almost-impossible-to-kill feature.

Comment: Revanant is probably better. But ... yeah... you're a sworn servant of a god-king actively working to consume all energy on your world. Race is one of those "handy extras." Even if you're "working against him" ... it's one of those things. I recommend a high bluff and fake platemail. Pretend to be a paladin :) Or... reflavour your class/race into something that works with the story you want to tell.